# The process cannot access the file 'C:\file.xml' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-io

```
 DirectoryInfo dir=new DirectoryInfo(path);
 if (!dir.Exists)
  {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
      File.Create(path + "\\file.xml");

      StreamWriter sw =new StreamWriter(path + "\\file.xml");
      sw.Flush();
      sw.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><project></project>");
  }
```

error:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\file.xml' because it is being
>   used by another process.

why? How can close file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx)

The FileStream object created by this method (File.Create) has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.

So the workaround is

```
  using(FileStream fs = File.Create(path + "\\file.xml"))
  {
       Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><project></project>");
       fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
  }
```

EDIT: Changed removing the creation of the StreamWriter and using a FileStream
However I don't like this way as suggested by MSDN.
StreamWriter has a constructor that can get a FileStream, but I thought that if we use

```
   using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path + "\\file.xml")))
   { 
      sw.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><project></project>");
   }
```

we get back the locking problem. However, I have tested and it works.
Probably the StreamWriter constructor do some tricks on the FileStream returned by File.Create.

Comment: error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'

Answer (score 1):

use `File.Create` or `StreamWriter`, not both

Comment: please write a sample that create and then add to

Comment: @user1263390 `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path + "\\file.xml", false);`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
File.Create(path + "\\file.xml");
```

To

```
File.Create(path + "\\file.xml").Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `sw.Close();` after you've called `Write();`

You may be better off using XmlDocument. Then you can append nodes like nodes etc.

XmlDocument has a built-in Save function so you don't have to manage any of that like a streamwriter.